# Factory reset Android x86

Tags: android, android-x86

I have installed the Android x86 in VirtualBox, but how to perform a factory reset?

Comment: What is MAKE and Model Version of your device?

Comment: It depends what version of android it is, but it'll be in the settings somewhere.

Comment: @ChintanRaghwani, I am using android-x86-2.3-RC1-eeepc.iso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the homescreen, press the menu button then navigate through:

**Settings->Privacy->Factory data reset**

Comment: When it reboot, it enter the grub and boot as normal, nothing happended.

Comment: That's because Android x86 doesn't ship with a recovery partition to reboot into.

Answer (score 2):

Boot in debug mode. in first console enter `exit` command. (now the data partition will be mounted)
Then you will get another console with higher resultion. run this commands:

```
cd data
rm -R *
exit
```

and you have wiped data partition including internal storage.

Comment: This worked essentially the way I wanted, which was to **wipe data** like the recovery menu.

Answer (score 0):

How about booting your "device" into recovery mode, where you can wipe data?
I assume that the following commands can be used:

```
adb shell reboot recovery
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817721/wipe-data-factory-reset-through-adb).

Comment: The grub prevent from booting into recovery mode

Comment: How can it prevent it? Are you not able to edit the options used for booting?

Comment: I can edit the grud menu, but how to make it boot into recovery mode?

Comment: That is (IMHO) a question you should ask the people who made android-x86. I see they have an IRC channel..