# How can I do factory reset using adb in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

How can I do the factory reset in android using ADB command? I had used adb reboot recovery command to get reset. But third party applications couldn't be cleared somehow.Is it correct way to achieve using ADB?

Actually, I want to do factory reset android devices through java code. What can be solution here?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817721/wipe-data-factory-reset-through-adb -- same answers though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is offtopic here (but ontopic on the https://android.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 92):

You can send intent **MASTER_CLEAR** in adb:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MASTER_CLEAR
```

or as root

```
adb shell  "su -c 'am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MASTER_CLEAR'"
```

After Android 8.0 and above with root permission from shell

```
am broadcast -p "android" --receiver-foreground -a android.intent.action.FACTORY_RESET
```

Comment: Amazing, didn't think that it would work, but in my case it helped! (it was a cheap overmax tablet, where I couldn't even access fastboot, nor recovery --wipe_data helped!)

Thanks!

Comment: Note: On most devices you will need to be root for this to work, else you will not have the appropriate permission to send this broadcast. Before running this command, use `adb root` to restart your phone's shell with root privileges

Comment: This command is not working in Android-OMR1 saying background execution not allowed.

Comment: This works for Devices which are rooted. But if Device is not Rooted than it is not working. It Doesn't give any response. Any Idea?

Comment: I just get Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MASTER_CLEAR }
Broadcast completed: result=0 :(

Comment: @TheClansman Same output i am having when i try with non rooted device. Did you find any other solution for this?

Comment: Worked for me on non-rooted device, just did adb root then adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MASTER_CLEAR

Comment: You must reboot the device after you run the command, so you can just type 'am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MASTER_CLEAR; reboot' and it will reset the device.

Comment: Worked on rk3188 tablet. Thank you!

Comment: didn't quite work for me due to background execution/implicit intent restrictions that have been introduced, see here for my solution: https://blog.deanwild.co.uk/android-factory-reset-via-adb-intent

Answer (score 21):

Try :

```
adb shell
recovery --wipe_data
```

And here is the list of [arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817721/wipe-data-factory-reset-through-adb) :

```
* The arguments which may be supplied in the recovery.command file:
 *   --send_intent=anystring - write the text out to recovery.intent
 *   --update_package=path - verify install an OTA package file
 *   --wipe_data - erase user data (and cache), then reboot
 *   --wipe_cache - wipe cache (but not user data), then reboot
 *   --set_encrypted_filesystem=on|off - enables / diasables encrypted fs
```

Comment: Hi EvZ,
WILL adb shell
recovery --wipe_data clear the third party applications?

Comment: It should I used it a while ago,but you can try.

Comment: @EvZ that ends up with "segmentation fault". any clue ?

Comment: If you get "segment fault" error, try the following commands: adb shell wipe data; adb reboot;

Answer (score 15):

#### Warning

From @sidharth: "caused my lava iris alfa to go into a bootloop :("

---

For my Motorola Nexus 6 running Android Marshmallow 6.0.1 I did:

```
adb devices       # Check the phone is running
adb reboot bootloader
# Wait a few seconds
fastboot devices  # Check the phone is in bootloader
fastboot -w       # Wipe user data
```

Comment: caused my lava iris alfa to go into a bootloop :(

Comment: @Sidharth oh no! Do you think I should delete this answer - if it's dangerous? Or hopefully your comment is enough of a word of warning.

Comment: I guess you could edit your answer and put out a warning for others.

Comment: My phone has been hanged after this solution. Fortunately other solution helped me to solve my problem  (My phone - xiomi mi5 android 6.0.1).

Answer (score 14):

I have made it from fastboot mode (Phone - Xiomi Mi5 Android 6.0.1)

Here is steps:

```
# check if device available
fastboot devices
# remove user data
fastboot erase userdata
# remove cache
fastboot erase cache 
# reboot device
fastboot reboot
```

Comment: I had to use adb reboot bootloader  first, but it worked

Comment: I had to use `adb root`and `adb reboot bootloader` before executing these commands, otherwise my device gets stuck.