# Google glass stuck at "Glass" logo screen

Tags: android, reset, google-glass

Google glass 2 stuck on the "Glass" screen, I tried restarting it, but it shows the logo and nothing changes.

I tried to make a factory reset - holding the camera button, clicking on the power button, and continue holding the camera button. I show me the recovery screen with options, but nothing is selectable, clicking on camera button won't let me select or click anything.

Is there any way to make a full factory reset to fix this "Glass" screen issue to make it working again?

Comment: Have you tried to do a factory reset with ADB as described here: [How can I do factory reset using adb in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685721/how-can-i-do-factory-reset-using-adb-in-android), [How to factory reset android using adb](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/175885/how-to-factory-reset-android-using-adb)

Answer (score 0):

This is the factory reset commands with adb in your command line:

```
adb reboot bootloader //device will restart
fastboot devices //this will print a device code if it worked right
fastboot erase userdata
fastboot erase cache
```

Then manually reboot device. You'll need [adb and fastboot](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools).

If that doesn't fix the problem, **and you don't care about keeping a warranty intact**, you can re-flash the firmware. If you care about a warranty... use the warranty.

The firmware is available for the Explorer Edition [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/system), if it's Enterprise E2 it'll be [here](https://developers.google.com/glass-enterprise/downloads/system-images). Enterprise  E1 firmware isn't available freely as far as I know, so if it's EE1 you're out of luck.

The firmware files come with a text file which contains the adb commands you need to run. Run them all in the order they're written. The final one will restart your device. Voila. Clean slate.

If it still doesn't work after that, it's a hardware problem.