# Android/Eclipse emulator how to wipe-data?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I got below errors while trying the above question . does anyone know what's going wrong?

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554 device

$ emulator -avd -wipe-data
PANIC: Could not open: -wipe-data

$ emulator -avd emulator-5554 -wipe-data
PANIC: Could not open: emulator-5554
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10829600/813951

Answer (score 30):

Open command prompt,

```
android-sdk-windows\tools>emulator -avd -wipe-data
```

example-

```
emulator -avd androidavd2 -wipe-data
```

Answer (score 17):

You can wipe data while starting emulator in ADT plugin, just mark checkbox: [image]

Comment: I know this option exist but I would like to know how to do it via CLI

Comment: You get to this "Launch Options" menu by clicking the "Start" button on the right-hand menu

Answer (score 7):

So I know this question is a few years old. But I'm going to answer anyways because no answer has been accepted.

FIRST, make sure that (your-android-sdk-location)/tools is on your $PATH. It wouldn't hurt to verify this by using `which emulator` from the terminal. For example when I do this it outputs:

```
/Users/chris.w.newman/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator
```

SECOND, find where your AVDs are located. By default it is located in the .android/avd directory in your User account folder. So for me it is here:

```
/Users/chris.w.newman/.android/avd
```

THIRD, `cd` to  the above directory and get the list of devices you have created by listing them with `ls`

```
chriswnewmans-MacBook-Pro:~ chris.w.newman$ cd /Users/chris.w.newman/.android/avd
chriswnewmans-MacBook-Pro:avd chris.w.newman$ ls
Nexus_5_API_19.avd  Nexus_5_API_19.ini
```

Note that every device has a pair of results, an .avd folder and an .ini file. You can see that I have one device whose name is Nexus_5_API_19.

FOURTH, to wipe the data of the device from the terminal you use the emulator -wipe-data command. Some people might find this annoying because it will ALSO launch the emulator after it finishes wiping the data. Anyways here's how you do it:

```
emulator -avd Your_Device_Name -wipe-data
```

The main reason I find this approach to wiping data annoying is that now the emulator is running from the terminal. That means if I wanted to do more work in the terminal, I would either need to open another terminal (I hate having multiple terminals open), or close my emulator to free up the terminal.

For completeness sake, I will mention that you can wipe the data of an emulator from the AVD manager (at least the one that is built into Android Studio). Open the AVD manager and in the list of devices, all the way on the right hand side you click the dropdown arrow and select Wipe Data. This wipes the data without launching the emulator.

Answer (score 3):

I have Windows10 and using Android Studio 3.4

Follow the steps:

`Tools -> AVD Manager -> Right Most Button under Actions(Down triangle Icon) -> Wipe Data`

This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dV49.png) shows the steps in a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
emulator -list-avds
```

EMULATOR_NAME will be displayed

```
 emulator -avd EMULATOR_NAME -wipe-data
```

Example:

```
emulator -list-avds
Pixel_XL_API_29

emulator -avd Pixel_XL_API_29 -wipe-data
```